# Terraform - Add arn of resource only if it exists to IAM policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-iam

My pipeline is going to be run across several different AWS accounts. Some accounts have all the S3 buckets needed, while some are missing some of the buckets.

I need my IAM policy to include ARNs of all S3 buckets if they exist. If an account has some s3 buckets that do not exist, those ARNs should be omitted from the policy. Something along the lines of:

```
#Check if S3 bucket 1 exists
data "aws_s3_bucket" "1" {
count =  "${var.bucket1_exist == "true" ? 1 : 0 }"
  bucket = "bucket1"
}
.
.
.
.
#Check if S3 bucket N exists
data "aws_s3_bucket" "N" {
count =  "${var.bucketN_exist == "true" ? 1 : 0 }"
  bucket = "bucketN"
}

#Dynamic IAM policy
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "conditional" {
  statement {
    sid = "1"

    actions = [
      "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
      "s3:GetBucketLocation",
    ]

    resources = [
      "data.aws_s3_bucket.1.arn",
      .
      .
      "data.aws_s3_bucket.N.arn",
  }
}
```

Is there any way I can dynamically set this IAM policy? I know Terraform requires explicit declaration of existing resources, but is there no way to work around dynamic environments with similar code?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you can't do what you want?

Comment: Thanks for the response! Haven't gotten around to making this implementation yet, but will try to create an external resource for this. For the time being, doing some manual intervention and tf imports to acknowledge these resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with plain TF as **TF does not have functionality** to check if something exists or not. For such functionality you would have to develop probably an [external resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source) in TF for that. You could also do same with [aws_lambda_invocation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/lambda_invocation).

What ever you choose, its ultimately up to you to **implement logic** for checking if something exists or not.